# Arithmetic books for adults

Tags: primary-education, reference-books, arithmetic, book

I'm trying to learn arithmetic from scratch again. Even though I can use it, I'm not sure if I can teach it to someone and I believe if you can't teach something properly, there might be loopholes in your understanding. Hence, I'm looking for a book that discusses various topics of arithmetic, like numbers (counting, fractions, integers, rational, real), numerals, place value number systems, addition, multiplication, division, etc very explicitly.

Comment: See [Which topics and textbooks to learn elementary school arithmetic and beyond?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1963961/13130) Maybe also [Books about elementary mathematics written like a good undergraduate textbook](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/1857/745), especially if you're more theoretically inclined (but still rusty with the mechanics of basic arithmetic).

Comment: **Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1963961 ?**

Comment: Would you be interested in mathematics education textbooks intended for training teaching students to become mathematics educators?

Comment: @nick012000 Yes, anything works as long as it is detailed on the arithmetic concepts.

Answer (score 5):

You might check out the [OpenStax Prealgebra text](https://openstax.org/details/books/prealgebra-2e). It seems to have much of what you’re looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[https://www.amazon.com/Math-Ages-SAT-High-School/dp/B08P2XRCLR/ref=sr_1_3?crid=1TWKUIXC302BL&keywords=high+school+maths&qid=1673731187&s=books&sprefix=high+school+math%2Cstripbooks-intl-ship%2C184&sr=1-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08P2XRCLR)

I have used this book to help me understand mathematics and prepare for my exams. It is helpful for all levels and the explanations are clear and friendly.

:)

Answer (score 1):

I would unironcially recommend Tao's Analysis-1. The issue of pinning down numbers as a logically consistent concept is much more complicated than one may think it to be.